# facial image recognition using LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

i tried following code for facial emotion recognition using deep learning based model LSTM but its not work.using python 3.7 anaconda3. this code works on CNN model.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:\\Datasets\\gender CK+\\training_set',
target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:\\Datasets\\gender CK+\\test_set',
target_size = (64, 64), batch_size = 32, class_mode = 'categorical')

seq = Sequential()
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3),input_shape=(None, 64, 64, 40),
    padding='same', return_sequences=True))seq.add(Batch Normalization())
seq.add(Dense(2,activation="sigmoid"))
seq.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
seq.summary()
seq.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 100, epochs = 4, validation_data = test_set, validation_steps = 200)
```

following error occurs

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv_lst_m2d_4_input
>   to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 64, 64, 3)

Comment: Why would you use an LSTM for this?

Comment: LSTMs are meant for sequences or time series data, you don't seem to have either.